# unboundLocalError:local variable 'connSkt' referenced before assginment

Tags: python-2.7

I am writing some codes to scan ports with Python. However, the error keeps showing up, I am not sure how to fix.

## Error is listed below:

```
[+] Scan Results for: ubuntu
[-] 80/tcp closed
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "portscanner.py", line 23, in connScan
    connSkt.close()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'connSkt' referenced before assignment
```

I did some research and appeared that I did not declare the variable properly, but I double checked the code and could not see what is wrong with it. Here is the tutorial I followed:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IOvvjNi8OdU&list=PL1A2CSdiySGLtKwqBnqj9BON6QQjWkP4n&index=5

```
def connScan(tgtHost,tgtPort):
        try:
                connSkt = socket(AD_INET, SOCKET_STREAM)
                connSkt.connect((tgtHost,tgtPort))
                connSkt.send('Hello\r\n')

                results = connSkt.recv(100)
                screenLock.acquire()
                print "[+] "+ str(tgtPort) + "/tcp open"
        except:
                screenLock.acquire()
                print "[-] "+ str(tgtPort) + "/tcp closed"
        finally:
                screenLock.release()
                connSkt.close()`
```

any advise would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When  socket creation fails with an exception, the variable connSkt is not yet *created/defined* in the Python interpreter. In that case, the call to close in the "finally" clause, is being invoked on an *undefined* variable. Hence, the interpreter is complaining.

Responding to follow-up question, one way to avoid this in the above (using LYBL approach):

```
connSkt = None
try:
    ...
except:
    ...
finally:
    screenLock.Release()
    if connSkt:
        connSkt.close()
```

An [EAFP approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360858/what-is-the-eafp-principle-in-python) might catch the exception but with my C-background, I am not quite comfortable catching exception for UnboundLocalError.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. May I know how to create/define connSkt in python interpreter? or another alternative way to fix it?